# How to use aria-attribute (aria-labelledby) for combo box (input+autocomplete list) correctly?

Tags: attributes, accessibility, wai-aria

How can I  use the aria-attribute `aria-labelledby` for combo box (input+autocomplete list) correctly?

According to the W3C, the `aria-labelledby` property provides the user with a recognizable name of the object. 
I've found the following example on W3C:

```
  <div class="combobox-wrapper">
    <div>
      <input type="text"
       aria-labelledby="ex1-label">
    </div>
    <ul aria-labelledby="ex1-label"></ul>
  </div>
```

But I've noticed that `aria-labelledby` isn't descriptive. Values in `aria-labelledby` for different element are used the same. 
Maybe I can use `aria-labelledby` like this:

```
<div class="combobox-wrapper">
  <div>
    <input type="text"
       aria-labelledby="textBox">
  </div>
  <ul aria-labelledby="autocomplete-list"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The WAI ARIA attribute `aria-labelledby` is used when you can't use the normal `<input>` + `<label>` combination to label a form element, e.g. because you are using a custom form element. In other words, it is used in situations where you can't use the `<label>`'s `for` attribute to define a label for the input (e.g.
`<input id="communitymode" name="communitymode" type="checkbox"> <label for="communitymode">communiti wiki</label>`; note that the `for` attribute's value refers to the input's `id` attribute.)

With `aria-labelledby`, your reference works in the opposite direction as the `for` attibute: you tell the browser or the screen reader where to find the "label" for the form control it has just encountered.

```
<div class="combobox-wrapper">
  <div>
    <span id="combolabel">Select your country:</span>
    <input type="text"
       aria-labelledby="combolabel">
  </div>
  <ul aria-labelledby="combolabel"></ul>
</div>
```

In the above code sample, both the `<input>` element and the `<ul>` element are labelled by the `<span>` element with `id` "combolabel".

Answer (score 0):

Remember the first rule of ARIA is don't use ARIA when native HTML elements exist. If you are trying to create an accessible autocomplete box try this:

http://wet-boew.github.io/v4.0-ci/demos/datalist/datalist-en.html

It does not use ARIA and follows all applicable W3C rules and guidelines.